# An EKR type card deck of a childrens card game

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

You want to print a deck of cards of the following type: Each card shows $k$ items out of $n$ different items such that any two cards in the deck share exactly one item.

> Question: **What is the biggest size of such a deck ?**

If you replace "exactly one" by "at least one", this is the classical Erdős-Ko-Rado problem, so I expect this question to be discussed before.

I appreciate both an explanation and any references discussing it.

Also, I have been computing a (very) few numbers and they **appear to not be listed in the OEIS**, though it is an array in $n$ and $k$, so there are variances how to search the OEIS for it.

Background: such decks of cards exist as a children's two-player game where both players open one card each and the player first naming the common item gets both cards. The player getting all cards wins.

Comment: finite projective spaces... https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobble
http://oeis.org/A090503
http://oeis.org/A258777

Comment: It would be good to list the few numbers you've got...

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: do you want to turn this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Here are some (n k max_size) values: 4 2 3, 5 2 4, 5 3 2, 6 2 5, 6 3 4, 6 4 1, 7 2 6.